# How to add more details children inside useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have the following data where useRef contains following information.

Data

```
{
    token: '', 
    id: '',
    versionId: '',
    additionalId: ''
}
```

The above is coming from the children within the useRef() as follows.

```
const formRef = useRef();
// other logic

// above Data
const aboveData = formRef.current.children;
```

Is there a way I can append to `children` to hold `overallInfo` block as follows?

```
{
    token: '', 

    // these 3 no longer needed but can remain if no way to delete
    id: '',
    versionId: '',
    additionalId: '',

    // I want to add this additional block
    overallInfo: {
      id: '',
      versionId: '',
      additionalId: ''
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the form

```
const Form = ({
  formRef,
}) => (
  <form id="form" ref={formRef} method="POST">
    <input name="token" type="hidden" />
    <input name="id" type="hidden" />
    <input name="versionId" type="hidden" />
    <input name="additionalId" type="hidden" />
  </form>
);

export default Form;
```

OverallInfo is not coming from anywhere.
I am purposely wrapping those 3 keys again cos client needs it to come in that format when I post.

This is how I am posting it. currently which is wrong cos I am not wrapping it inside OverallInfo.

```
export const PostForm = (
  formRef,
  link,
) => {

  // formRef.current.children definitely has all the token, 
  // id, versionId and additionalId values at this stage

  formRef.current.action = link;
  formRef.current.submit();
};
```

SOLUTION SUGGESTION BELOW:

```
export const PostForm = (
    formRef,
    link,
) => {
  const updatedRequest = {
      overallInfo: {},
  };

  [...formRef.current.children].forEach((child) => {
    updatedRequest.overallInfo[child.name] = child.value;
  });

  const newRef = useRef(updatedRequest);

  newRef.current.action = link;
  newRef.current.submit();
};
```

Comment: `formRef.current.children` will be undefined in the current example?

Comment: Please update the question to show us how you're using the ref (I'm guessing `<form ref={formRef} ...`, but...). Also, where would the `overallInfo` come from and why do you want to add it to the `children` of the `form` (if I'm guessing right)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It won't be undefined, it has values. Issue is more on how I could wrap it inside the overallInfo key.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the question to show how to form is used and how I am posting it.

Comment: @karvai thank you for updating the question. T.J. Crowder's answer is still valid. You cannot manipulate DOM representations of HTML as if you would a regular JS object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't get the solution. Could you see update above under SOLUTION SUGGESTION BELOW. Is that what you and T.J meant?

Comment: @karvai their answer has disappeared since I wrote the comment. - The main question I have is what do you want to do with that object?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am looking to send it as a request body when I post it / perform the above .submit(). Same way how the request does go through currently with correct values when the .submit() is performed. Only issue is that it is not wrapped inside the overallInfo key.

Comment: This might help? https://sebhastian.com/react-submit-form/

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks but this change will involve changing a lot of other existing logics we have.